# "We're not" vs. "we aren't"

Tags: grammar, contractions

I'm just curious if there are any "official" rules (or opinions either way) about what form to use when three words can be contracted on either side.

Comment: Given these are primarily *spoken* forms, and that ordinarily we're only going to apply **one** of the two possible contractions, I imagine we tend to just apply the first one *because it comes first* - by the time we get to the second one it's just too late to get a look-in. I don't think this implies any difference in meaning - it just shows we don't plan all our speech that far in advance.

Comment: I think it depends to some degree on dialect. I'm sure that "I'll not" is not as rare in Northern England and Scotland as in the South (though I think "I won't" is more common everywhere).

Comment: Interesting counter-example to the "it comes first" theory, Colin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, since they do mean the same thing, I would think that they are generally interchangeable. Both are grammatically valid, but there is one reason to use one over the other; if you are trying to increase the emphasis on one word, don't contract it. For example, if I am trying to emphasize the fact that we're not [something]:

> We're not criminals.

If you are trying to emphasize the fact that there are multiple people, you might use *we aren't:*

> We aren't going to let you take our pets!

(To me, the first has more emphasis on *not* than the second does on *we*.)

That's the only difference I can see; other than that, there probably aren't many others. Also, [NGrams claims](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we%27re+not%2Cwe+aren%27t&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that *we're not* is more popular:
[image]